# Test if dataframe column contains any elements of vector

Tags: r, vector, compare

I have the following dataframe, df:

```
    Alpha      Beta     Gamma
1     100       36      Dollar, Euro, Yen
2     120      -33      Euro
3     150       14      Yen, Peso
```

I have another vector, currencies = c("Dollar", "Yen")

I want to generate a new column that lists:

- 1 if "Gamma" contains any elements of currencies
- 0 if "Gamma" contains no elements of currencies

I try:

```
df$Epsilon <- ifelse(any(df$Gamma %in% currency), 1, 0)
```

But this doesn't work.  Upon closer inspection, each row in df$Gamma is interpreted as **one** string, (ie, "Dollar, Euro, Yen" instead of "Dollar", "Euro", "Yen"), so %in% isn't working properly.

```
splits = lapply(strsplit(df$Gamma,','), trimws)
```

does the job of breaking the values up, but I can only reference them for comparison with %in% by using double brackets (ie, splits[[i]]]), which I can't do for every value in the list.

How can I achieve my result?

Comment: I would think the `strsplit` option would be safest in case one currency is contained in another like "dollar" and "dollarydoos" (the official Australian dollar). - `sapply(strsplit(df$Gamma, ",\\s+"), function(x) any(currencies %in% x))` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
transform(dat,yy=grepl(paste0(currencies,collapse="|"),Gamma)+0)
  Alpha Beta             Gamma yy
1   100   36 Dollar, Euro, Yen  1
2   120  -33              Euro  0
3   150   14         Yen, Peso  1
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution can be achieved using `stringr::str_detect` as:

```
library(stringr)
df$Epsilon <- as.numeric(str_detect(df$Gamma, paste(currencies, collapse='|')))

df
#   Alpha Beta             Gamma Epsilon
# 1   100   36 Dollar, Euro, Yen       1
# 2   120  -33              Euro       0
# 3   150   14         Yen, Peso       1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
'Alpha      Beta     Gamma
100       36      "Dollar, Euro, Yen"
120      -33      Euro
150       14      "Yen, Peso"',
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

currencies = c("Dollar", "Yen")
```